# tbl_uvregression does not report an estimate of the reference category for linear regression

Tags: r, gtsummary

The option `add_estimate_to_reference_rows` in `tbl_uvregression` allows one to request an estimate of the reference category to be reported for regression results.  For `family = binomial` it works as expected, the reference category is `1.0` when `exponentiate = T`.

However, for `family = gaussian`, `add_estimate_to_reference_rows = T` returns zero as the estimate, and not the value of the intercept.

An example with the trial data follows.

```bash
# glm: linear regression with reference estimate added
tbl_uvregression(trial[, c('trt', 'age', 'stage', 'marker', 'death')], method = glm, y = marker, method.args = list(family = gaussian), exponentiate = F, add_estimate_to_reference_rows = T) %>%  modify_column_hide(columns = p.value)
```

Expect `add_estimate_to_reference_rows` to return the intercept.  It returns zero.

Comment: Intercepts and reference groups are entirely different. Zero is the correct addition. There is a separate argument to add the intercept

Comment: I'd say that: 1) the intercept is a parameter to be estimated,  2) interpretation of the intercept depends on the choice of the reference group.

I imagined that setting "add_estimate_to_reference_rows = T" would add an estimate of the reference (group) to the table.  In this case, that would be the estimated intercept.  The table has a column labelled "beta" for estimated regression coefficients.

But, the option does not add an estimate.  It reports zero in the column labelled "beta".  Zero is not an estimate of a regression coefficient in this case.  Perhaps it is a model constraint?

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to the "intercept" option.  I didn't see it in documentation for tbl_uvregression, but I see it is there for tbl_regression, and it does add the estimated intercept as expected.

Comment: BTW, I do think gtsummary is a terrific package!

Comment: One final comment in the spritit of making a very good function even better.

A useful table would be one with the layout achieved presently by setting "add_estimate_to_reference_rows = T", but with the value of the estimated intercept in the column labelled "beta" (instead of a fixed value equal to zero or one).  Setting "intercept = T" provides the value, but creates a cumbersome table layout.  Morevover, "beta" equal to a fixed value of zero or one isn't meaningful when "family = gaussian".

Comment: Can you refer me to a published table (eg in a peer-reviewed journal) that summarizes a regression model in the way youre suggesting?

Comment: I rarely see tables of unadjusted, i.e. "univariate", regression results in journal articles.  It is more common in my area to see descriptive stats and adjusted regression results at publication.  But, we do often circulate unadjusted regression results as preliminary findings for discussion among colleagues.  So, I think these tables are still very useful.

Comment: I thought we're discussing intercepts and reference groups. I don't see where univariable and multivariable regression models are coming into play?

Comment: There is only one intercept in a table of adjusted results.  The discussion is about the reference category using tbl_uvregression.

Comment: I am confused why 1 is the correct reference value when coefs are exponentiate, but 0 is incorrect when they are not exponentiated, eg `exp(0) = 1`. Regardless, we can just agree to disagree on this one! Hope you can still use the functions!